# Is it possible to directly bulk insert a table without creating a file to import from

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

SQL-Server has this great ability to `BULK INSERT` data from a file. However, in order to do that, the file must exist and be accessible from within the server.

Suppose we don't have file access to the server and furthermore there is no way the DB-server and I can share any directory or network path whatsoever.

I also read related questions and their answers, but have to admit that I am not truly satisfied with the answers. They usually state that it is not possible, but .NET has the `SqlBulkCopy` class, which can handle this, so it is technically possible. But when looking at the trace, I don't see how the transferred data is formatted.

Suppose I am using a programming language which has no access to .NET (but can access a Win32-DLL), what would be my possibilities?

I know, I could use the bcp tool for this, i.e. writing the data to a local file, create format information and run `bcp` in a process. But I would like to avoid it (just for aesthetic reasons).

Comment: What about this? [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b8908d1-fd6d-47a9-9e30-514cee8f60c8](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b8908d1-fd6d-47a9-9e30-514cee8f60c8)

Comment: I will give it a try. Seems to be the right source.